# How to write R code for mcmc of a changepoint logistic model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mcmc, piecewise

I want to write a mcmc code for a changepoint logitic model, 
my model is like this:

```
logit{p(x)}=beta0+beta1*doseA+(beta2-beta1)*(doseA-w)*I(doseA>w) +beta3*doseB+(beta4-beta3)*(doseB-v)*I(doseB>v)
```

in which these are parameters to estimate:`beta0-beta4,w,v;`

`x,doseA,doseB` are data provided

I have a Metroplis Hasting code for a simpler model:

```
logit{p(x)}=beta0+beta1*doseA+beta2*doseB
```

but I don't know how to deal with the changepoint parameters in my model, I wonder if they should be sampled together with other parameters or seperated. Plus, model before and after the changepoint has different number of parameters, so they use different priors, but I wonder if I should seperate my data for it.

I tried to use `rstan` for mcmc, but it was extremely slow. I hope I could write the mcmc code myself, or use some packages like "mcmc" or "HI"

```
# dose-toxicity probability model
#  input: doseA and doseB are vectors with same size, 
#        doseA[i] and doseB[i] comprise a dose regimen
#  output: p is a vector, p[i] is the prob. of doseA[i] and doseB[i] 
probfun = function(doseA,doseB,param){
  p = param[1]+param[2]*doseA+param[3]*doseB
  p = exp(p)
  p = 1-1/(1+p)
  return(p)
}

# log-likelihood of toxicity probability
#used by function logpostT
loglike = function(doseA,doseB,param,x,n){
  mu = param[1]+param[2]*doseA+param[3]*doseB
  lk = sum(x*mu-n*log(1+exp(mu)))       
  return(lk)
}

# Cauchy prior distribution
prior_c = function(b0,mub0,scaleb0){
  dcauchy(b0,mub0,scaleb0)
}

# posterior core for toxicity
#used by function mhT , to compute parameter posterior 
# input:doseA,doseB,x,n are input data, vectors with same size,
#       muT0,scaleT0,shapeT1,rateT1,shapeT2,rateT2 are hyperparameters for prior 
logpostT = function(doseA,doseB,param,x,n,muT0,scaleT0,shapeT1,rateT1,shapeT2,rateT2){
  h = loglike(doseA,doseB,param,x,n)+log(prior_c(param[1],muT0,scaleT0))+
    log(prior_c(param[2],shapeT1,rateT1))+log(prior_c(param[3],shapeT2,rateT2))
  return(h)
}
# candidate(proposal) density for toxicity
#used by function mhT , to provide new parameters for a new iteration
candiT = function(param,jsdb0,jsdb1,jsdb2){  
  a = rnorm(1,param[1],jsdb0)
  b = rnorm(1,param[2],jsdb1)
  c = rnorm(1,param[3],jsdb2)
  return(c(a,b,c))
}

# acceptance ratio in MCMC for toxicity
#used by function mhT , to compute r in Metropolis-Hasting algorithm, likelihood_new/likelihood_old*prior_new/prior_old
ratioT = function(doseA,doseB,x,n,b,bs,muT0,scaleT0,shapeT1,rateT1,shapeT2,rateT2){
  r = exp(sum(x*((bs[1]-b[1])+doseA*(bs[2]-b[2])+doseB*(bs[3]-b[3])))-       
            sum(n*(log(1+exp(bs[1]+doseA*bs[2]+doseB*bs[3]))-log(1+exp(b[1]+doseA*b[2]+doseB*b[3])))))*
    prior_c(bs[1],muT0,scaleT0)/prior_c(b[1],muT0,scaleT0)*
    prior_c(bs[2],shapeT1,rateT1)/prior_c(b[2],shapeT1,rateT1)*prior_c(bs[3],shapeT2,rateT2)/prior_c(b[3],shapeT2,rateT2)
  if(is.na(r)==T) r=Inf
  return(r)
}

# Metropolis-Hasting algorithm for toxicity
mhT = function(doseA,doseB,x,n,muT0,scaleT0,shapeT1,rateT1,shapeT2,rateT2,jsdb0,jsdb1,jsdb2,size,burn,thin){

  start = c(-5,5,5)

  b_pre = start
  n_var = length(b_pre)
  ac = matrix(0,size,n_var)
  draws = matrix(NA,size,n_var)
  post = c()       

  for (i in 1:size) {
    b_cand = candiT(b_pre,jsdb0,jsdb1,jsdb2)
    b_old = b_pre

    #sequential updated every parameter in each iteration
    for (j in 1:n_var){
      #give the b_star based on the b_old and b_cand
      if (j==1) {
        b_star = c(b_cand[j],b_old[(j+1):n_var])
      } else if (j==n_var) {
        b_star = c(b_old[1:(j-1)],b_cand[j])
      } else {
        b_star = c(b_old[1:(j-1)],b_cand[j],b_old[(j+1):n_var])
      }
      #calculate ratio and determine whether to accept or not
      r = ratioT(doseA,doseB,x,n,b_old,b_star,muT0,scaleT0,shapeT1,rateT1,shapeT2,rateT2)
      if (runif(1)<r) {
        b_new = b_star
        ac[i,j]=1
      }else {
        b_new = b_old
        ac[i,j]=0
      }
      b_old = b_new 
    }

    draws[i,] = b_new
    post[i] = logpostT(doseA,doseB,draws[i,],x,n,muT0,scaleT0,shapeT1,rateT1,shapeT2,rateT2)
    b_pre = b_new
  }

  return(list(draws=draws[seq(floor(size*burn)+1,size,thin),],post=post[seq(floor(size*burn)+1,size,thin)],ac=apply(ac,2,sum)))
}
```

Comment: If `dose` means what I think it means, maybe look at `drm(drc?)`?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by drm(drc?)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `drc` package that deals with dose-response relationships.

Comment: I think the more fruitful path is to get help with your Stan code rather than trying to write your own sampler. Try asking on [the Stan Discourse site](https://discourse.mc-stan.org) about why your model is running slower than you expect.

Comment: I‘ll have a try, thanks for your suggestion